# How to find a user from another forest with UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, principalcontext

Here is some sample code:

```
var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var up1 = AuthenticablePrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Sid, "S-1-5-21-.......");
var up2 = AuthenticablePrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, "login@contoso.com");
```

If the user is in the same domain where this code is executing, it finds the user in both cases. If the user is in another, two-way trusted forest, both return null.

When I create a domain-local group on the current domain and put users from other forests in it, and I list the members of the group with `GroupPrincipal.GetMembers`, it does find and it does resolve the foreign objects as well. So this task is certainly possible and our infrastructure is also working fine.

How to find a user from another forest with `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity`? Or with any other method that uses `PrincipalContext`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an ugly solution with reflection:

```
var ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
var queryCtx = ctx.GetType().GetProperty("QueryCtx", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(ctx, null);
var ctxBase = (DirectoryEntry)queryCtx.GetType().GetField("ctxBase", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(queryCtx);
var srch = new DirectorySearcher(ctxBase);
srch.Filter = "(objectSid=S-1-5-21-.......)";
var result = srch.FindOne().GetDirectoryEntry();
var adUtils = queryCtx.GetType().Assembly.GetType("System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADUtils");
var up = (UserPrincipal)adUtils.GetMethod("DirectoryEntryAsPrincipal", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).Invoke(null, new object[] { result, queryCtx });
```

Comment: You might be able to skip the first reflection by simply doing `var ctxBase = new DirectoryEntry();`.  Out of curiosity, does ctx.Name == up.Context.Name?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `PrincipalContext` [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298328%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that allows you to specify the name of the target context - the DNS name of the target forest/domain.

Comment: I do not know the target context in advance. I only have one context.